# Accessing class from different package in command line

Tags: java, class

I have created two folders in C:\Users\Documents folder. I have named the folders as A and B. Inside folder A, I have written below java class.

```
package A;

public class Food {
int a =6;
public int c = 10;
}
```

Inside folder B, I have below class written,

```
package B;
import A.*;

public class Car {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     Food food = new Food();
     System.out.println(food.c);         

 }
}
```

I am able to compile class Food from inside folder A. But when I am trying to compile class Car from inside folder B, I am getting below compilation error. How to resolve this?

```
Car.java:2: error: package A does not exist
import A.*;
^
Car.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
     Food food = new Food();
     ^
symbol:   class Food
location: class Car
Car.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
     Food food = new Food();
                 ^
symbol:   class Food
location: class Car
3 errors
```

Comment: You need to compile your classes from **Documents** foolder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be in the `Documents` folder to get access both the packages A & B while compiling `Car` class.

And your compile statement must be something like

```
javac -cp . B/Car.java
```

*Note: I put classpath as current directory(.) considering .class files are available under it.*

To run the class `Car` use the below command.

```
java -cp . B.Car
```

While running Class with main(), you need to give full qualified path of class name i.e. `packagename.className`

Comment: I am able to compile the class Food as per your suggestion. But when I run the class ( java -cp . B\Car) from Documents folder I am getting error as below:  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:                                                                         B\Car (wrong name: B/Car)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)

Comment: You have to give .java extension as well

Comment: Why .java extension is needed for running compiled class?